# Fork and Join in Activity Diagram

Tags: uml, activity

Consider the following Activity Diagram :

[image]

First of all the activity a22 is confusing me through this configuration .If we need to list all the possible activity sequences that can take place in this activity diagram. My answer is as follows :

Sequence one : a11 ; parallel combination of a22 , a33 and a44 ;a77.

Sequence two : a11  ;parallel combination of a22 , a33 and a44 ; parallel combination of a55 and a66.

Is this a right answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost.

The first answer is ambiguous. It's

`a11` followed by `a22` running in parallel to [ `a33` || `a44` followed by `a77` ].

That finalizes when `a77` is done. `a22` can't reach the termination since it's stuck at the synch bar.

The second is also incorrect.

`a11` followed by `a22` running in parallel to [ `a33` || `a44` followed by `a55` || `a66` ]

So it finalizes when `a22`, `a55` and `a66` have finished. Which ever takes longest.